# Custom controls in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible create such element on base UITabBarController?

[image: tab bar with segmented control]

If not, how do you advise create it. Thank you,

Comment: Try using UISegmentControl for that.

Comment: StackOverflow is primarily meant for debugging code and programming concepts in general. Your question is really too broad to give a specific answer. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can easily add a `UISegmentControl` to a UITabBarController. If you check Apple Documentation UITabBarController accepts [UITabBarItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem) which can be initialize with either an image/String or with one of the preset cases.

You could create your own TabBar and then add a UISegment Control onto that, but if I was you I would use the normal UITabBarController and make the two buttons one next to the other with images that makes it look like a segment control to the user.

The issue with this approach that the TabBar is not supposed to be there for you to have more than one item selected at a time. So you could not have notes and All selected at once.

It might be easier for you to add the UISegmentControl onto a UINavigationController at the top of your app, and then use the TabBar normally.

That is what I would do in any case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible create such element on base UITabBarController?

**No,** you cannot add your own controls to a tab bar. The tabs in a tab bar should be used as they're intended, i.e. to switch between several different view controllers.

> If not, how do you advise create it.

I recommend that you *don't* try to create something that both switches between view controllers and also does other things. That said, if you want to add controls that work differently from tabs in a bar at the top or bottom of the window, [UIToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitoolbar) is the right class to use. You might be able to create a subclass of UIBarButtonItem that has radio-button functionality similar to what UISegmentedControl offers, and you could then use that with UIToolbar.